# AdMob RewardedVideoAd keeps running in background

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

So I have a field:

`private lateinit var adMobAd: RewardedVideoAd`

and I initialize it in onCreate() method:

`adMobAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this)`

which I destroy in onDestroy() method:

`public override fun onDestroy() {
        adMobAd.destroy(this)
        super.onDestroy()
    }`

but when I click the button to load an ad and then leave activity quickly, an ad is showed few seconds later (i show ad in `onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()` callback). It is very bad behaviour, specially when ad is not skippable. It also calls callback when it is done, so I got crashes of course. In addition, I use some mediations to my rewarded videos like

`implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:3.1.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:tapjoy:11.11.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:2.1.0.0'`

How can I prevent this case?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add a flag and check if the ads is available first before you show the ad?

```
fun onDestroy(){ isDestroyed =true  ...}
```

in the button click, you check if the ad is already loaded or the activity is being queued to be destroyed.

```
if(admobAd.isLoaded() && !isDestroyed){ admobAd.show() }
```

Comment: well of course i can do that. I expected more admobish answer, because according to documentation, my implementation should be working. In addition, onDestroy() method is not guaranteed to be called and also there is flag `activity.isDestroyed()`

Answer (score 0):

OnDestroy isnt always called, so also use OnPause, so one of them will be called. In your Activity, destroy the ad in the onPause method. Add this code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    adMobAd.destroy(this);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I don't want to destroy an ad when user simply minimize screen. that is why `adMobAd.pause(this)` method is called in `onPause()` method.

Comment: then add the `onResume` method and load it and show it in the `onResume` method

Comment: it means you request for an ad, load it and then display every time user maximize screen, which is very bad pattern. this is why in `onResume()` method you should call `adMobAd.resume(this)`.